# JavaScript programa ocupando arreglos con los números pares comprendidos entre 1 y 20 y los muestre en pantalla en orden ascendente porfavor ayudenme

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Que tengo mal?
No me aparece nada solo me sale undefine
var pares = Array(20)
var cont, i
cont = 0

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
    i=i+1
    if ( i%2 == 0) {
        pares[cont]=i;
        cont++;
    }
    
}

for (var i = cont + 1; i <= 20 ; i++) {
    document.write(pares[i]+"<br>")
}
```

Comment: 1) declara arriba de todo el array y el contador "let pares = []; let cont=0". 2)  i=i+1 --> eso bórralo. 3) El ultimo for es  for (var i = 0; i < pares.length ; i++)

Comment: Otro método es que vayas de 2 en 2 en tu primer for: for (var i = 2; i <= 20; i =i+2). Este for da los pares inmediatamente, no hay que hacer ningún if

Answer (score 2):

Se podría hacer algo así:

```js
//Variable auxiliar donde se guardarán los números pares.
const numeros = [];

//Aquí se agregan al array numeros todos los números pares entre 1 y 20.
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  if (i % 2 === 0) numeros.push(i);
}

//Aquí se itera el array numeros y se muestra en pantalla, el <br> genera un salto
//de línea
for (const numero of numeros) {
  document.write(numero + "<br>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías hacerlo también con un for:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    document.write(i+"<br>")
  }
}
```

Comment: Es verdad, pero no cumple con la letra ya que indica que debe ser un arrays

Answer (score 0):

Ya que estamos dando respuestas, dejo la mia

```js
let pares = [];
for (var i = 2; i <= 20; i =i+2 ){
  pares.push(i);
}

for (let p of pares) {
  document.write(p + "<br>");
}
```